# sound card not detected in 16.04 ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, soundcard

I recently upgraded from ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 but I can't detect sound card, all I see in settings/sound - dummy output, nor the headphones jack is working , but both were working fine in 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try `sudo alsa force-reload`

I had to try several other things and at last this ..

this should work in most cases